# PHP Multiple conditions issue

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to show the bootstrap alert box based on below condition

```
// These arrays can be empty if not set

$operations = [] // array of operations
$positions = [] // array of posisionts
$employees = [] // array of employess
```

Now I want to show alert box if any of these arrays is empty or the `current employee` is in their respective array. I am stuck to find the robust way to do. As I believe simple `if(){}else{}` condition might not work. Like this what I have tried.

```
if (
    ( empty( $operations ) || in_array( $this->cur_operation, $operations ) ) ||
    ( empty( $positions ) || in_array( $this->cur_position, $positions ) ) ||
    ( empty( $employees ) || in_array( bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees ) )
) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box( $type, $message, $dismissible, $id );
}
```

This condition is showing alert all the time.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

## Additional Note

Probably I didn't explain well above.

> What I am looking for is whether array is empty or the current user's
> item is in array in both conditions I want to show the alert box

It is kind or permission or rule if it is empty then visible to everyone but if it has a value then show only to the specific user who has the value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
if (
( empty( $operations ) || in_array( $this->cur_operation, $operations ) ) &&
( empty( $positions ) || in_array( $this->cur_position, $positions ) ) &&
( empty( $employees ) || in_array( bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees ) )
)
```

Comment: I have already tried with `&&` but then it is not showing if the field hasn't set anything. Means if array is empty

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep empty and !empty condition in its own `||` block as follows,

```
if (
    ( empty($operations) || (!empty($operations) && in_array($this->cur_operation, $operations)) ) ||
    ( empty($positions) || (!empty($positions) && in_array($this->cur_position, $positions)) ) ||
    ( empty($employees) || (!empty($employees) && in_array(bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees)) )
) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box($type, $message, $dismissible, $id);
}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It might do the trick :

```
$operations = ["foo"];
$positions = ["bar"]; 
$employees = ["moo"]; 

function shouldTrigger($array, $data = ""){
    return empty($array) ? true : in_array($data, $array);
}

if(shouldTrigger($operations) || shouldTrigger($positions, "bar") || shouldTrigger($employees)){
    echo("Empty array or index found");
};
```

You might go further in `shouldTrigger()` like checking if `$data` is empty or not.

Comment: Looks promising. let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you who provided their support with the answer and tried me to help. Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked for me and finally I come up with this solution myself.

Please provide me your input if you find any possibility to optimize the code.

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    var_dump( NULL );
} else if ( empty( $operations ) && empty( $positions ) && empty( $employees ) ) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box( $type, $message, $dismissible, $id );
} else if (
    ( in_array( $this->cur_operation, $operations ) ) &&
    (
        ( ! in_array( $this->cur_position, $positions ) ) || ( ! in_array( bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees ) )
    )
) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box( $type, $message, $dismissible, $id );
} else if (
    ( in_array( $this->cur_position, $positions ) ) &&
    (
        ( ! in_array( $this->cur_operation, $operations ) ) || ( ! in_array( bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees ) )
    )
) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box( $type, $message, $dismissible, $id );
} else if (
    ( in_array( bp_loggedin_user_id(), $employees ) ) &&
    (
        ( ! in_array( $this->cur_operation, $operations ) ) || ( ! in_array( $this->cur_position, $positions ) )
    )
) {
    echo ac_get_alert_box( $type, $message, $dismissible, $id );
}
```